# Text in Excel for concatenate and substitute

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is it able to concatenate a text from one cell and substitute the particular text?

Example Column B - "MC.11"
Column N - "4.23 Agile Programming with high priority".

Needed result - "4.23 MC.11 Agile Programming with high priority"

Column B has different tag in each cell.

Please advise

Comment: Is the start from Column N always the same length, i.e. always 4 characters (4.23) long? If so, just use LEFT/RIGHT (pretty sure this time substitute won't help you faster). `=LEFT(N2,5) & B2 & " " & RIGHT(N2, LEN(N2)-5)`

Answer (score 2):

You could try this using `SUBSTITUTE()` function

[image]

• Formula used in cell `C1`

```
=SUBSTITUTE(B1," "," "&A1&" ",1)
```